# Help finding a suitable transformer

Tags: transformer, ultrasound, piezo

I have built a circuit that can drive a 3.3v AC output at a few hundred mA. The wave has a frequency of 150Khz. I want to step this up to 60-90v at ~0.5 Watts to drive an ultrasonic piezo. However, I am having difficulty finding a transformer. From what I understand, I am looking for one with a coil ratio between 1:20 and 1:30, and a relatively small VA. I would also like the transformer to be as small as possible (low height is more important than small footprint). I have looked on common electrical supply house websites like Digikey, but their filters aren't all that helpful. Coil ratio is never a filter option, and anytime I find one that I think might work, it is made to operate at 60Hz. Also, when I search "1:30," I get results for current transformers, and I don't believe that these are suitable for my application. I would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to search for a transformer and possibly some suggested devices.

Secondly, I am not positive that I am on the right track for this project. The circuit that I created is a class E amplifier. Should I be feeding Vcc 60-90v DC (by using a flyback converter, for instance) rather than throwing a transformer on the output? The idea is to prioritize making the circuit small with some consideration for efficiency. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is a good chance you could just use something like a Triad Magnetics FS20-120-C2 and run it 'backwards'.  Being made for 60 Hz is likely not a problem at these levels...a bit more resistive/lossy is all I would expect.

Comment: @evildemonic 60 Hz to 150**kHz**?  It may be more than a bit more lossy.  But it's probably worth a try.

Comment: There's a lot of difference between a transformer designed for 50 / 60Hz and one for use at 150kHz. The Triad product appears to have a laminated iron core which is fine for mains frequencies but will almost certainly be very lossy at 150kHz. I would think you need to look at high frequency ferrite cores and a custom design.

Comment: With the stipulation that I may be completely off base -- you may want to wind one.  DigiKey should be able to sell you E-cores, bobbins and clips.  It would be up to you to do the designing, though.

Comment: Would running this one backwards be a problem: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik-Midcom/750871013?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvwUzoUXIIvyXUf6nVydy8boi%252B%2FVwxAGtk%3D

Comment: Considering that you want to minimize size, check out Coilcraft's coupled inductors: https://www.coilcraft.com/LPR6235.CFM

Comment: @BenWatson, this might be exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it out an let you know!

Comment: ok, I may have downplayed the lossy-ness, but it really might just work.  The laminations will be too thick (more eddy current = more loss), but we are not talking about much current.  I wouldn't do it in a product, but to get a piezo up and running, I wouldn't hesitate to give it a shot since it is easy and cheap.